# Node.js & express.js preview in VSCode

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

So I'm learning backend and I'm doing a simple express.js experiment. I'm using a simple GET HTTP Protocol to preview an HTML (index.html). I'm working in *replit.com* and I could see the preview of the index.html file that is created:

[image: index.html preview on Replit]

I could also get a JSON respond from a code that I've wrote if I go to link *my-replit-link.co/json*. This is the javascript code that I've wrote to preview the index.html and preview json on ***'/json'*** using express.js:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
})

app.get('/json', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        "message": "Hello json"
    })

module.exports = app;
```

But I'm trying to do it also in VSCode. Is there any way I could preview like in *replit.com* using VSCode?

Any helpful answer would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Obviously, you can do the same thing in your VS code. For that you need to setup on your local machine. Online Platforms like Replit gives you basic structure ready that's the reason you don't know how to setup Node & all other things.

Comment: Adding onto @GulshanAggarwal's comment:
You'll probably need to `npx express-generator` & `npm install` on VSCode. Also see [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-node) for creating an Express & Node.js application with VSCode.

Comment: @clxrity & Gulshan thanks for the response, I'll try to read!